# Prisma Playground is giving token invalid error

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I am getting following error when I try to access Prisma Playground in browser.

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": " Your token is invalid. It might have expired or you might be using a token from a different project.",
      "code": 3015,
      "requestId": "api:api:cjfcbpal10t6w0b91idqif941"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You would need to generate prisma token using following command and pass it as authorization header in the playground:

```
prisma token
```

[image]